# How to use LinkedIn pixel event tracking in single page application

Tags: single-page-application, linkedin, tracking-pixel

How can I use LinkedIn pixel on a specific event in Angular 5 app?
I got this crappy code from our SEO team:

```
<img height="1" width="1" style="display:none;" alt="" src="https://dc.ads.linkedin.com/collect/?pid=XXXXXX&conversionId=XXXXXX&fmt=gif" />
```

And it should run when a user completes registration. How can I fire it from code when the HTTP call is resolved. Facebook as way better documentation.

Comment: Why is that code crappy?   It looks like standard pixel tracking to me.   I don't know much about SPAs, but I expect you can insert HTML into the DOM with them whenever you need to.

Comment: Maybe I'm doing something wrong. Facebook has this fbq() function that I can use on event thats why I think its way easier to use from js code.
My case looks like this: User is filling registration form hits submit - then if the http call was succesfull I need to send this `pixel` but adding it then doesn't work because the view is already changed.

Comment: Maybe `document.write('<img ....`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks for all the input Stephen.
I have finally got a solution. I've placed a tag like this `<div [innerHtml]='linkedinPixel'>` and am filling this variable with a proper link via service.

Answer (score 3):

I solved this with the following:

```
const img = new Image();
img.src = `https://dc.ads.linkedin.com/collect/?pid=${linkedinPixelId}&conversionId=${linkedinEvent}&fmt=gif`
```

Here's a link to the LinkedIn documentation which wasn't obvious to find:

https://www.linkedin.com/help/linkedin/answer/93957